# spring JTable creation throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, jtable

I have a spring configuration which reliably throw exception with the following configuration file:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
 default-init-method="init">

 <!-- GUI tables --> 

 <bean id="basket.summary.table.model" class="javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel" />
 
 <bean id="basket.summary.table" class="javax.swing.JTable">
  <constructor-arg ref="basket.summary.table.model" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

And the exception I got is as following:

```css
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2890
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:114)
 at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:86)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
 at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
 at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.aso.algo.gui.system.GuiMain.main(GuiMain.java:39)
```

I think the example is simple enough but I still couldn't figure out what caused the problem. It basically failed to construct the `JTable` object. I tried to specify the parameter class for the `constructor-arg` but no luck.

Anyone could help me please? Must missing some simple thing.

Comment: Which Spring and Java versions? Looks like an incompatible versions (i.e. old spring version on JDK8).

Comment: @M.Deinum wow, indeed? It's spring RC 3.1.2 on JDK 1.8.0_31.

Comment: The ASM version shipped with that version isn't compatible with JDK 1.8. You would need to upgrade to a 4.x version.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please kindly write the above to an answer so I could accept. Thanks you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older Spring versions aren't compatible with JDK 1.8, especially due to the internally packaged ASM library which isn't compatible.

JDK 1.8 support was added in Spring 4, so you would need to upgrade to one of those.